# UITextFiled without border unexpected behavior on unicode characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, uitextfield

I need to add unicode characters like "îăâșț" in my textfield, but i notice that if textfield is without border you can see adjusting effect and if textField has border the behaviour is as expected no adjusting.

I have tried to add border with white color but there is some shadow left, Also tried `self.textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;`

**How can I have the same behaviour for UITextField without border as UITextField with border?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing with settings i notice if you adjust the content insets by overriding:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
```

or simply by adding a left View

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
self.textFieldName.leftView = paddingView;
self.textFieldName.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

and also keep in mind that `self.textField.minimumFontSize` should be smaller otherwise the jumping effect will persist